Java: Running asynchronous task using executorService
I have two end point /issue and /callback, and /callback will be called immediately after /issue is called. In issue i submit a task to executor service and store the future to a map with key as order id and value as the future returned by the executor service and when callback is called it will fetch the future from the map using the orderid and wait for the issue task to complete(using map.get(orderid).get()) and then procedes. now suppose i call /issue and the task is submitted and /callback is called even before the future is stored in hashmap, and Map.get(orderid).get() throws an error? i want to make sure future goes into map, before /callback is called. How can this be done?
public class CallbackServiceImpl implements CallbackService {

    private final OrderService orderService;
    private final OrderRepository orderRepository;
    private final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    private final Map<String, Future<?>> issueCertificateFutureMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    private final Map<String, Future<?>> renewCertificateFutureMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    @Override
    public IssueCertificateAsyncResponseDto issueCertificateExecutorService(ConfirmSSLOrderRequestDto confirmSSLOrderRequestDto){
        String orderId = confirmSSLOrderRequestDto.getOrderid();
        Runnable issueCertificateRunnable = () -> {
          try {
              orderService.issueCertificate(confirmSSLOrderRequestDto);
              log.info("ISSUE ORDER COMPLETED for order {}", confirmSSLOrderRequestDto.getOrderid());
          }
          catch (Exception e){
              log.error(e.getMessage());
              throw new AppException(e.getMessage());
          }
        };
        Future<?> issueCertificateFuture = executorService.submit(issueCertificateRunnable);
        issueCertificateFutureMap.put(orderId, issueCertificateFuture); //I have to make sure this goes into the map
        return IssueCertificateAsyncResponseDto.builder()
                .caOrderId(confirmSSLOrderRequestDto.getOrderid())
                .build();
    }
    private void handleIssueOrderCallbackRequest(SSLIssueOrderCallBackDto sslIssueOrderCallBackDto){
        String orderId = sslIssueOrderCallBackDto.getCaOrderId();
        Runnable issueCertificateCallBackRunnable = () -> {
            try{
                issueCertificateFutureMap.get(orderId).get(); // before this gets executed
                //do callback task
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                throw new AppException(e.getMessage());
            }
            finally {
                issueCertificateFutureMap.remove(orderId);
            }

        };
        executorService.submit(issueCertificateCallBackRunnable);
    }
}


On first check of the map, if no entry is found, why not wait a moment (sleep the thread) and try again?

By the way, be sure you gracefully shut down your executor service before your web app ends.

When issueCertificateExecutorService returns, the Future is certain to be in the Map. I don't understand the problem.

The /issue api response will not be returned until the completion of pushing the data to map so there is no problem I see.You mentioned after /issue /callback so the ordering is taken care

I think what you are looking for is synchronization between 2 threads, while you have the first one as a producer and the second one as a consumer
The simplest solution according your code would be to synchronize them with wait / notifyAll
When you call "wait" on a thread, you make it stop execution and give other threads the option to run, it will stop until another thread invokes notify / notifyAll on the object, in my example "this" is used
An example solution would look like this:
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

public class CallbackServiceImpl implements CallbackService {

    private final OrderService orderService;
    private final OrderRepository orderRepository;
    private final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    private final Map<String, Future<?>> issueCertificateFutureMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    private final Map<String, Future<?>> renewCertificateFutureMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    @Override
    public IssueCertificateAsyncResponseDto issueCertificateExecutorService(ConfirmSSLOrderRequestDto confirmSSLOrderRequestDto){
        String orderId = confirmSSLOrderRequestDto.getOrderid();
        Runnable issueCertificateRunnable = () -> {
            try {
                orderService.issueCertificate(confirmSSLOrderRequestDto);
                log.info("ISSUE ORDER COMPLETED for order {}", confirmSSLOrderRequestDto.getOrderid());
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                log.error(e.getMessage());
                throw new AppException(e.getMessage());
            }
        };
        Future<?> issueCertificateFuture = executorService.submit(issueCertificateRunnable);
        issueCertificateFutureMap.put(orderId, issueCertificateFuture); //I have to make sure this goes into the map
        synchronized (this) {
            notifyAll();
        }
        return IssueCertificateAsyncResponseDto.builder()
                .caOrderId(confirmSSLOrderRequestDto.getOrderid())
                .build();
    }
    private void handleIssueOrderCallbackRequest(SSLIssueOrderCallBackDto sslIssueOrderCallBackDto){
        String orderId = sslIssueOrderCallBackDto.getCaOrderId();
        Runnable issueCertificateCallBackRunnable = () -> {
            try{
                synchronized (this) {
                    while (!issueCertificateFutureMap.containsKey(orderId)) {
                        // before this gets executed
                        wait(); // you could add some timeout, so 
                    }
                }
                issueCertificateFutureMap.get(orderId).get(); // before this gets executed
                //do callback task
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                throw new AppException(e.getMessage());
            }
            finally {
                issueCertificateFutureMap.remove(orderId);
            }

        };
        executorService.submit(issueCertificateCallBackRunnable);
    }
}```

The reason I have while loop is because you might be notified for different orderIds, and you want to be waiting for the one that in the map
You may want to exit the loop after sometime, so maybe a timeout to "wait" is a better option, its just depends on your needs

